# VB.Net: Convert SQL (Pseudocode) to Dymanic LINQ Query from List<Custom> Parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, linq-to-sql, union

Okay guys.  I'm a noob.  I know (some) programming, a little SQL, and scant LINQ to SQL.

**GOAL**: Bind nested ListViews to LINQ generated iQueryable of anonymous type.  I want to use LINQ because you can use GroupBy and bind the nested ListView to the 'it' keyword.

**SETUP**: I have groups of sets of conditions.  Each set of conditions is stored in the BillingCodes table.  Each group of BillingCodes is stored in the BillingGroups table.

I have a custom object that stores the ID, Name, and NumCodes for each BillingGroup that the user has chosen.

I have a collection of these objects called GroupsList that has a list of the groups that the user has chosen.

**Problem 1**: I can iterate through GroupsList and grab all the IDs.  How do I translate the SQL 'WHERE ID IN(a string of comma delineated IDs)' for LINQ to SQL?  Is that the best way to do that?

**Problem 2**: Once I have the list of BillingGroups I need to iterate through each group.  For each group, I need to iterate through the BillingCodes.  For each BillingCode I need to generate a WHERE clause that has all of the conditions in the BillingCode.  I propose something like so:

```
for each BillingGroup in BillingGroups
    for each BillingCode in BillingGroup.BillingCodes
        where1 = "..." 
    next
next
```

**Problem 3**: Here's the part where I don't have a clue.  I need to dynamically create a query in LINQ to SQL.  Keep in mind that I don't know how many groups there'll be or how many codes are in each group.

There are 2 tables:

```
**transactions**
transaction_id
patient_id
svc_date
code
charge
description

**v_patients**
first_name
last_name
patient_id
date_of_birth
insname
active
provider_name
```

I imagine a query that looks something like this:

```
[Group1] Select MAX(svc_date), patient_id, transaction_id
From (

Select transaction_id, patient_id, svc_date
From transactions join v_patients on patient_id
[Code1] Where code=”” and description contains “” and insurance contains “” and charge >= PriceFloor and charge <= PriceCeiling

UNION

Select transaction_id, patient_id, svc_date
From transactions join v_patients on patient_id
[Code2]Where code=”” and description contains “” and insurance contains “” and charge >= PriceFloor and charge <= PriceCeiling

)
Group By patient_id

UNION

[Group2] Select MAX(svc_date), patient_id, transaction_id
From (

Select transaction_id, patient_id, svc_date
From transactions join v_patients on patient_id
[Code1]Where code=”” and description contains “” and insurance contains “” and charge >= PriceFloor and charge <= PriceCeiling

UNION

Select transaction_id, patient_id, svc_date
From transactions join v_patients on patient_id
[Code2]Where code=”” and description contains “” and insurance contains “” and charge >= PriceFloor and charge <= PriceCeiling

)
Group By patient_id
```

**Problem 4**: Lastly, I want to wrap that query in one that groups by patient_id.  Something that end in Select as New With {key, it as transactions, num as count()}

I have pieced together this knowledge with endless reading and searches.  I'll continue to look for answers, but any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT - ANSWER:**

Here's the code that ended up working for me:

```
Dim chosenIDs() As Short = (From p In GroupsList _
                                   Select p.ID).ToArray()

        GroupMatchListView.DataSource = Nothing

        If chosenIDs.Length > 0 Then

            Dim db As New AudioRxInternalDataContext
            Dim vf As New VersaformDataContext

            Dim chosenGroups() As BillingGroup = (db.BillingGroups.Where(Function(m) chosenIDs.Contains(m.ID))).ToArray()

            Dim wholeResults As List(Of transaction) = Nothing

            For Each chosenGroup As BillingGroup In chosenGroups
                Dim groupResults As List(Of transaction) = Nothing
                For Each chosenCode As BillingCode In chosenGroup.BillingCodes

                    Dim codePredicate = PredicateBuilder.True(Of transaction)()
                    codePredicate = codePredicate.And(Function(i) i.code.Equals(chosenCode.Code))
                    If Not chosenCode.Description Is Nothing Then codePredicate = codePredicate.And(Function(i) i.description.ToUpper().Contains(chosenCode.Description.ToUpper()))
                    If Not chosenCode.Insurance Is Nothing Then codePredicate = codePredicate.And(Function(i) i.v_patient.insname.ToUpper().Contains(chosenCode.Insurance.ToUpper()))
                    If Not chosenCode.PriceFloor Is Nothing Then codePredicate = codePredicate.And(Function(i) i.charge >= chosenCode.PriceFloor)
                    If Not chosenCode.PriceCeiling Is Nothing Then codePredicate = codePredicate.And(Function(i) i.charge <= chosenCode.PriceCeiling)

                    If groupResults Is Nothing Then
                        groupResults = vf.transactions.Where(codePredicate).ToList()
                    Else
                        groupResults.AddRange(vf.transactions.Where(codePredicate).ToList())
                    End If
                Next

                groupResults = groupResults.GroupBy(Function(r) r.patient_id).SelectMany(Function(g) g.Where(Function(r) r.svc_date = g.Max(Function(a) a.svc_date))).ToList()

                If wholeResults Is Nothing Then
                    wholeResults = groupResults
                Else
                    wholeResults.AddRange(groupResults)
                End If
            Next

            Dim conditionsPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True(Of transaction)()
            conditionsPredicate = conditionsPredicate.And(Function(i) i.v_patient.active = "Y")
            conditionsPredicate = conditionsPredicate.And(Function(i) i.svc_date >= StartDateBox.Text)
            conditionsPredicate = conditionsPredicate.And(Function(i) i.svc_date <= EndDateBox.Text)
            If Not OfficeDropDownList.SelectedValue = "Both" Then conditionsPredicate = conditionsPredicate.And( _
                Function(i) (If(i.v_patient.provider_name, "").ToUpper().Contains(OfficeDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToUpper())))

            wholeResults = wholeResults.Where(conditionsPredicate.Compile()).ToList()

            Dim goliath = From f In wholeResults _
                          Group f By f.v_patient Into Group _
                          Order By v_patient.last_name, v_patient.first_name, v_patient.date_of_birth _
                          Select New With {.PatientID = v_patient.patient_id, .LastName = v_patient.last_name, .FirstName = v_patient.first_name, _
                             .DOB = v_patient.date_of_birth, .Ins = v_patient.insname, .MatchCount = Group.Count(), .Matches = Group}

            GroupMatchListView.DataSource = goliath

            theMatchesLabel.Text = goliath.Count()
        Else
            theMatchesLabel.Text = "0"
        End If
```

Don't ask me why I used `goliath` for the final variable.  I created that bit of code late at night, and the previous attempt had been named `david`.

Thanks for everyone's suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Shame on me : I didn't use VB, but c#. But I hope some answers should help a bit...

**Problem 1 :** grab a list or array of int (or string) named Ids, for example and use

```
.Where(m => Ids.Contains(m.Id)
```

If the list of Ids comes from Database, I think you have to make 2 queries...

**Problem 2 :** not really clear with the infos you give, but the use of

```
SelectMany(x => blabla)
```

somewhere should do the trick (but once again hard to say like so)

**Problem 3 :** here also not really clear : what's the interest of you union in same groups ? If the difference are only codes, why not use the system of Problem 1 ?

To build "dynamic queries", I can just say that IQueryable can be build "on demand", like classic code, for example

```
var query = blabla;
if (searchCriterion.Name != null)
  query = query.Where(m => m.Name == searchCriterion.Name);
```

**Problem 4 :** I use a "ToDictionary()" extension, as you seem to need a KeyValuePair, but they are of course other ways.

```
GroupBy(m => m.TransactionId).ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Count)
```

But... if you could be a little bit more concrete, maybe ;)

**Edit Problem 4 :**
didn't read well, rather something like that

```
GroupBy(m => m.TransactionId).Select(g => new {
patientId = g.Key,
transaction = g.SelectMany(p => p.Transactions),
num = g.Count());
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!  It furthered my understanding of the problem.  I realized I didn't know enough and found a c# book to read.